# extjs 4.2 pagination not controlling the pageSize

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

I have an ajax store as following:

```
buildSearchStore: function(storeID, storeType, resultFields, pageSize) {
    var extraParams = '&type='+storeType+'&entitiesID='+windowData.entitiesID;
    return Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId: storeID,
        remoteFilter: true,
        fields: resultFields,
        pageSize: pageSize,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            noCache: false,
            url: this.statics().BASE_SERVER_URL+extraParams,
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'rows'
            }
        }
    });
}
```

In the front end I am having a grid defined by this store which I am trying to put the PagingToolbar for that grid as such :

```
this.bbar = Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
               store: this.store,    
               displayInfo: true,
               pageSize:10,
               displayMsg: 'Records {0} - {1} of {2}',
               emptyMsg: "No records to display",
            });
```

Everything works fine in this except the grid is showing all the records and I wanted to show the grid with the batch of 10 records at a time.
I have seen the documentation that if i use the proxy as Memory or something is working for others but it did not worked for me as I cant afford to have a memory proxy anyway. any help around this issue would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is that paging, ultimately, is up to you. The "paging" that Ext JS provides doesn't actually control the data which is returned from the server. Rather, it merely sends through page/limit/start, etc. in order to help you know what you need to do on the server-side to return the correct data set that Ext JS can use in the "paged" data.

In other words, Ext JS is showing all the records precisely because that is what you're giving it. If you want paged data to work in the grid, you'll need to update your server side code to accommodate the page/limit/start directives which Ext JS sends you in order to construct the proper data set to return.

http://existdissolve.com/2014/01/ext-js-4-demystifying-grid-paging/